# Telethon make user reply to the sent message

Tags: python-3.x, button, telethon, reply

[image: Code should work like this] I'm writing a telethon bot that should do the following:

1. Bot listens to the messages sent by users in the channel.
2. To the message '/start', bot greets the user with 'Hi {username}!'
3. Bot makes the user auto reply to the message sent in step #2 (as if the user clicked the reply button of the message received from bot)

So far, I tried this code.

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events


api_id = 'api_id'
api_hash = 'api_hash'
channel_id = 'channel_id'


client = TelegramClient("session", api_id, api_hash)
@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=channel_id, pattern="/start"))
async def handler(event):
    sender = await event.get_sender()
    response = f"Hi [{sender.first_name}](tg://user?id={sender.id})!"
    await event.respond(response)
    await event.click(0)


client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Code doesn't give any errors, but the button is not clicked either.

Comment: Your question is not understandable. please do more explaining on what you exactly want, are you a bot or the user, what sort of "click" are you expecting? have you checked out passing the argument buttons=Button.force_reply that will make the user auto reply to your sent message? https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/custom.html#telethon.tl.custom.button.Button.force_reply

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I edited my question to make it understandable. Plus, I got the solution using Button.force_reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
from telethon.tl.custom.button import Button

api_id = 'api_id'
api_hash = 'api_hash'
bot_token = 'bot_token'
bot = TelegramClient("bot", api_id, api_hash).start(bot_token=bot_token)

async def main():
    async with bot:

        @bot.on(events.NewMessage(pattern="/start"))
        async def handler(event):
            sender = await event.get_sender()
            response = f"Hi [{sender.first_name}](tg://user?id={sender.id})!"
            await event.respond(response, buttons=Button.force_reply("some text"))

        await bot.run_until_disconnected()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).